# First half of the prints are getting stretched on the Z axis

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis, bltouch, layer-height, th3d

I have an `Ender 3 Pro` with a `BLTouch 3.1` attached and I have this weird problem. Whatever I print, whether it's a 3rd party STL or my own design, the Z is always getting stretched up to a point and then it fixes itself.

i.e. I printed these calibration cubes at 100% and 150%. While there is a slight wobble on the X axis, X, Y and the top half dimensions are almost perfect.

[image: Z prints higher than it should]

Not sure if I had this problem prior to BLTouch installation, so I suspect that it might be messing Z jump between the layers somehow but no idea what to look for.

I am using TH3D's Marlin Firmware and I did nothing other than enabling the corresponding flags for BLTouch and ENDER_V44_BOARD when compiling the firmware.

- The problem occurs on my custom designs and other models too, so it's definitely not the model
- I tried to use Simplify3D, Ultimaker Cura, Prusa Slic3r to slice and then print with Octoprint, Simplify3D or Pronterface, it didn't make a difference.
- I calibrated the E steps, so I am not no under or over-extruding.
- I also tried to re-calibrate the Z steps so the height would match, which it did but didn't solve the problem. I now have a squished top half and a weird looking print.
- The steps/mm values were at default, X80, Y80 and Z400 - as described, reducing the Z to 320 to compensate the height difference didn't help. See the picture below.

[image: Squished top half after reducing the Z steps]

I am pretty much stuck at this point, so I'd appreciate any guidance very much!

Comment: I just found out about the `fade height` right after posting this. Guess I am suffering from the same: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/creality-ender-3-pro-z-travel-issue-with-th3d-firmware

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `DEFAULT_LEVELING_FADE_HEIGHT` of the TH3D firmware was causing the issue, which was something I was aware of but didn't think that it would cause this.

I set it to zero and then re-printed the calibration cube. It came out with the dimensions of 20 mm x 20 mm x 20.1 mm, which was incredibly accurate for the setup I have.

Related: [Creality Ender 3 Pro - Z travel issue with TH3D firmware](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/creality-ender-3-pro-z-travel-issue-with-th3d-firmware)

Comment: Nice.  Yet another reason I don't feel the need for BLTouch.